# Accessing repository through related entity in Symfony2/Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

This is similar to this question posted previously:
[In Symfony2, should I use an Entity or a custom Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374339/in-symfony2-should-i-use-an-entity-or-a-custom-repository)

Lets say I have a car entity and a Wheels entity. A car has many wheels but a wheel has a single car.

In my controller I already have access to the car. I'm using the relation to get the wheels belonging to the car.

```
$car = $this->getCar();
$wheels= $car->getWheels();
```

The above works and gives me access to the wheels belonging to the current car. But instead of getting all wheels, I only need wheels where flat = 0.

Is there a better way than a repository to get the wheels belonging to the car entity where flat = 0?

I was thinking of creating a getter in the car entity (getNonFlatWheels) then filtering the wheels so that only the non flat wheels are returned.

Seems there would be a more standard solution.

Comment: Your entity should not contain business logic; create a CarRepository and put your query in that, like Simone does below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know your entities structure, but in a similar situation I use this snippet of code. You can try to put it in CarRepository class.

```
/**
 * Get all non flat wheels
 *
 * @return Result
 */
public function getNonFlatWheels()
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $query = $em
            ->createQuery("
                SELECT g
                FROM Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Car c
                JOIN c.wheels w
                WHERE w.flat = :flat
            ")
            ->setParameter('flat', 0);

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Your code snippet is searching for **all** cars that doesn't have flat tires (flat = 0) but I think the question was how to get only the non flat tires for a **given** car object

Answer (score 3):

Simone's answer should do it, but again, it kind of depends on your entity structure and what you want to do with your $wheels object.

For instance, and assuming you have a recent version of Twig installed, you can loop through $wheels keeping only the ones where flat = 0 as so:

```
{% for wheel in wheels if wheel.flat == 0 %}
    //do whatever
{% endfor %}
```

Hope it can be useful